# Couldn't find instance of overloaded function .erase matches the argument list (vector) AND no operator "=" matches this operands

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase, operands

So I'm working on this collision detection and I get 4 errors:

- E0349 no operator "=" matches these operands
- E0349 no operator "=" matches these operands
- E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=, _Alloc=std::allocator<>]" matches the argument list
- E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=, _Alloc=std::allocator<>]" matches the argument list

So the problem is with iterators and I have no idea how to fix them.

Here's the code:

```
    //Collision detection
    vector<Animal>::iterator it;
    vector<Texture>::iterator it2;
    vector<Enemy>::iterator e_it;
    vector<Texture>::iterator e_it2;
    for (int i = 0; i < animal.size(); i++) {
        it = animal.begin() + i;   //error here
        it2 = animal_texture.begin() + i;
        SDL_Rect animal_collider = animal[i].getCollider();
        if (checkCollision(mCollider, animal_collider)) {
            score += 100 * mult;
            animal.erase(it);   //error here
            animal_texture.erase(it2);
            animal_num++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < enemy.size(); i++) {
        e_it = enemy.begin() + i;   //error here
        e_it2 = enemy_texture.begin() + i;
        SDL_Rect enemy_collider = enemy[i].getCollider();
        if (checkCollision(mCollider, enemy_collider)) {
            score -= 50;
            --hp;
            enemy.erase(e_it);  //error here
            enemy_texture.erase(e_it2);
            enemy_num++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since we have no proper [mcve], I must resort to soothsaying and voodoo magic. My crystal ball tells me those aren't the *only* four items listed when compilation fails. The exact, complete, *verbatim* error messages should be included in your question, along with a proper [mcve] that produces the problem for *us*.

Comment: The error message says that the compiler believes `animal` is of type `std::vector< <error-type> >`. Your problem is not in the code shown, it starts earlier, where `animal` is declared.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik could be, but the "funny part" is, before I put this code along with headers, everything worked fine and it compiled successfully, but, when I used headers, the program returned these errors. Maybe the issue is with headers, what are your thoughts?

Comment: It is a fair assumption that the problem was introduced by whatever it is you did between "worked fine and compiled successfully" and "returned these errors". That's as much as I can say without seeing a [mcve].